# "for" loop x value?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get my second array to print `x` in increments but reset to zero once the case value changes.

Code:

```
array = ['2017001677', '2017001677', '2017001621', '2017001621']
array2 = ['2017001677', '2017001621']

x = 0
for case in array:
    for case2 in array2:
        if(case == case2):
            print(case2)
            print(x)
    x = x + 1
```

Current Output:

```
2017001677
0
2017001677
1
2017001621
2
2017001621
3
```

Desired Output:

```
2017001677
0
2017001677
1
2017001621
0
2017001621
1
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: If your input was `['2017001677', '2017001621', '2017001677', '2017001621']`, what would your output be?  `0 0 0 0` or `0 0 1 1`?

Comment: That would be the correct x value with element but I need the array to be in the original order

Comment: Arrays don't print things...so it's unclear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the counter for unique values in `array` by tracking the last-seen value, starting with `None`

```
array = ['2017001677', '2017001677', '2017001621', '2017001621']
array2 = ['2017001677', '2017001621']

last_case = None
for case in array:
    if case != last_case:
        x = 0
        last_case = case

    for case2 in array2:
        if(case == case2):
            print(case2)
            print(x)
            x = x + 1
```

Comment: Thats close, but it comes out wrong, I want it incremental for the duplicates. Your results: 2017001677
0
2017001677
0
2017001621
1
2017001621
1

what I want: 2017001677
0
2017001677
1
2017001621
0
2017001621
1